# Invariance of energy under translation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I'm trying to prove following relationship
$$
\dfrac{\hbar}{i} \dfrac{dH}{dx}(x,p) = \left[p, H(x,p)\right]  
$$

but I'm in trouble. Can someone help me?
I tried:
$$
[p_x, H] = 0\\
(p_xH - Hp_x) = 0\\
\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(H \phi(x)\right) - H\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\phi(x)\right) = 0\\
\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{dH}{dx}\phi(x) + H \dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d\phi(x)}{dx} - H\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d\phi(x)}{dx} = 0
$$
But, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can you show us where you get stuck?

Comment: You should include all relevant calculations you've done so far and clarify what concept you don't understand. In particular, you should define what $H(x,p)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what you have done in your answer,
\begin{align}
[p_x, H] \phi(x)
&= (p_xH - Hp_x) \phi(x) \\
&= \dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(H \phi(x)\right) - H\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\phi(x)\right) \\
&=\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{dH}{dx}\phi(x) + H \dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d\phi(x)}{dx} - H\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{d\phi(x)}{dx} \\
&=\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{dH}{dx}\phi(x).
\end{align}

This proves that

\begin{align}
[p_x, H]
&=\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{dH}{dx}, 
\end{align}
as you have asked.

Notice, however, that I didn't equal these expressions to zero. That is because they are not, in general, zero. They are only zero for systems where momentum is a good quantum number (e.g.: Free particle).

For a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator, for example:
\begin{align}
H_{QHO} = \frac{p^2}{2m} + k x^2 \\
[p_x, H_{QHO}]
&=\dfrac{\hbar}{i}\dfrac{dH_{QHO}}{dx} \\
&=\dfrac{\hbar}{i} 2kx\\
&\neq 0.
\end{align}